# По самое не(?)балуй(ся)

Tags: орфография, фразеология, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно писать слова, которые стоят в конце этого фразеологизма — слитно или все-таки раздельно?

> Всыплю тебе по самое не балуй, не балуйся и не хочу!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В любой позиции - раздельно.

См.: Словарь русского арго. — ГРАМОТА.РУ.
В. С.   Елистратов.  Жгучий глагол: Словарь народной фразеологии. — Зеленый век. В. Кузмич. 2000.
Словарь синонимов ASIS. В.Н. Тришин. 2013.

Примеры из корпуса.

Надо же, в конце концов быть последовательным: если демократия, так до победного конца, а если свобода―то, уж извините, **по самые не балуйся,** да со всеми вытекающими. **[Андрей Щиголев. Демократия тела // Известия, 2012.05.16]**

Когда обнаружили, что вдогоночку к утрате приборов наши мобильники не работали, лес стал казаться мрачным и зловещим, песни кончились, очарование незаметно переросло в раздражение, и ко всему прочему незадачливый исследователь Юрий прозаично провалился в болото по самые **«не балуйся».** **[Юрий СНЕГИРЁВ, Александр МЕШКОВ. Тайна «Чертова оврага» // Комсомольская правда, 2004.04.20]**

Получу за это **по самое не балуйся.** [**Александра Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают. Т. 1 (2014)]**

А вот банки и компании в середине 2000-х умудрились влезть во внешние долги **по самое не хочу.** **[Долговой карман: худой и еще худее // «Эксперт», 2013]**

Answer (score 1):

**Балова́ть, балова́ться** — формы повелительного наклонения от этих глаголов имеют вид **балу́й, балу́йся** (НЕ с любой формой глагола пишется раздельно).

[По самые не балуйся!](https://folklor.academic.ru/1430/%D0%9F%D0%BE)
Глубоко,чувствительно, использовав все возможности.

*Но и так уже **вляпалась по самое не балуйся**, так зачем отказывать себе в маленьких удовольствиях?* (О. Пашнина. Ведьма в шоколаде)

*Нет, всё же лучше будет сегодня хотя бы немного отдохнуть, тем более что завтра подниматься следует часа этак в четыре — **дел по самое не балуйся**...* (С. Ким. Без объявления войны)

*Так вот — бедные страдальцы **прикованы по самое не балуй**, так что даже повернуть голову не могут, но зато отчётливо видят эти тени* (П. Коршунов. Труды по новой философии).